# Preparing nested sorting filter using ES java library

Tags: java, sorting, elasticsearch

Some time ago I had an [issue with sorting results by one of values in nested documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393140/sorting-documents-by-value-in-one-of-nested-documents). It turned out the problem was with my query. Instead of:

```
"sort": [
   {
      "children.size": {
         "order": "desc",
         "nested_filter": {
            "term": {
               "id": 1
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I was using:

```
"sort": [
    {
      "children.size": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested_filter": {
          "nested": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "id": 1
              }
            },
            "path": "children"
          }
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Incorrect query was strongly inspired by code generated by ES library (elasticsearch-1.4.jar). Here's a snippet I've been using to prepare sorting part of the query:

```
FieldSortBuilder mySort = SortBuilders.fieldSort("children.size")
              .setNestedFilter(FilterBuilders.nestedFilter("children", FilterBuilders.termFilter("id", myId)))
              .sortMode("avg")
              .order(SortOrder.ASC);
```

When such "sort" is added to the query, the end result is improper nested filter.

Am using the library in a wrong way? How can I easily overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to this question appeared here, but somehow got removed. Anyway, it was explained to me that I am using wrong filter inside of method `setNestedFilter` - I should not provide there a nested filter, but it should be a term filter. Changing that seems to fix the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me :) I basically did removed your nestedFilter within your nestedFilter.